# CSS: side by side, same height

Tags: html, css, layout

I have written a simple side by side fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CwSD6/7/

When you change the size of the view section in the fiddle, than you see that the table (.text.meta) doesn't align anymore with the top border of the text.

Is there a simple fix for this problem so that both sections have same height?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this Fiddle [HERE?](http://jsfiddle.net/CwSD6/8/)

All I did was remove this line in both `.text` and `.text.details`:

```
display: inline-block;
```

And added this to both classes instead:

```
float: left;
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is it. Didn't knew about floating both elements :D